# Whats the fastest and most efficient way to travers a 3x3 / 5x5 pixel neighborhood?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV (C++) and I would like to know "whats the fastest and most efficient way to travers a NxN pixel neighborhood?" Priority has the fast aspect if memory usage doesnt grow horrendous high.

Currently I'm accessing in a 3x3 neighborhood each pixel simply this way:

```
// image is a OpenCV Mat
for (int i = 1; i < image.rows - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < image.cols - 1; j++) {
        // center
        int pixelValue = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
        // neighborhood
        int pixelValue1 = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i - 1, j - 1)[0];
        int pixelValue2 = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j - 1)[0];
        int pixelValue3 = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i + 1, j - 1)[0];
        int pixelValue4 = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i + 1, j)[0];
        int pixelValue5 = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i + 1, j + 1)[0];
        int pixelValue6 = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j + 1)[0];
        int pixelValue7 = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i - 1, j + 1)[0];
        int pixelValue8 = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i - 1, j)[0];
    }
}
```

This doesnt seem to be the fastest solution due to it takes quite some time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: to be cache friendly, you have to iterate in order (so the 3 (`i-1`) first by increasing `j`

Comment: looking at [filter2D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) might be a good idea ;)

Comment: i know about filter2D, but this just applies a matrix on that specific neighborhood, i would like to get the actual pixel values

Comment: What are you doing with the pixel values once you have them? I agree with @Jarod42 that processing everything you can on a single row before moving on is the only obvious place to look without further information. Perhaps getting a pointer to a row and accessing pixels by offset (assuming the Mat is continuous).

Comment: For every neighborhood some vectors are created with for example: {color of center, color center - color upper left corner, color center - color middle bottom .. and so on}. Thats why I cant just take a filter2D. Puh I'll have to get my head around how thats going to work with the pointer management when I'm trying to use a continuous matrix.

Comment: If you perform special tasks you might be able to precompute or share information, like: integral images, separated filters or optimizations like in non-maximum-supression. Everything general is just about caching. You could try to transform your image to a pixel ordering like it is used in Cuda Textures, there they use a memory ordering that tries to minimize memory distance for small pixel distances (= better caching).